# How to disable Firebase in-app messaging browser redirection on android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I want to open a specific activity on-click of buttons in firebase in-app messaging, by default it is redirecting to the browser.
I want to open relevant activity within my app itself if user clicks on action button. please suggest me how can I disable browser redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming again that you want to track which link a user clicked on a Card-style message, define a class that implements the **messageClicked** method per the **FirebaseInAppMessagingClickListener** interface, thereby providing you access to the in-app messaging Action object, which in turn exposes the **URL** in the link clicked by the user.

First, implement a click listener:

```
public class MyClickListener implements FirebaseInAppMessagingClickListener {

    @Override
    public void messageClicked(InAppMessage inAppMessage, Action action) {
        // Determine which URL the user clicked
        String url = action.getActionUrl(); // you can open the relevant screen.

        // Get general information about the campaign
        CampaignMetadata metadata = inAppMessage.getCampaignMetadata();

        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: I have implemented this interface callback  but still it is redirecting to browser app on click of action button. basically it is doing 2 things simultaneously - opening activity and also redirecting user to browser.

Comment: you can catch the relevant url and use intent

Comment: now I am able to open specific activity but the issue is I am unable to receive custom Key/value pairs data with in-app message using. I am using below lines of code to receive it -                                                                                                                   Map dataBundle = inAppMessage.getData();
Log.d("kk", "messageClicked: "+dataBundle);